# Bundling and Minification in Portable Area

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, modularity

I used '[Portable Areas](http://lostechies.com/erichexter/2012/11/26/portable-areas-3-years-later/)', It's great.

but now, what I want is something like this:

```
bundles.AddEmbeddedResources<ScriptBundle>("~/Test/Scripts",
            GetType().Assembly,
            "PortableAreaDemo.Test.Scripts",
            "index.js");
```

I used [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) Library, It's great.

I want to use this library with Bundling And Minification in asp.net for adding my javascript files into the project, but It doesn't work for me!
What should I do?

[Sample Project:](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qctv894403ry0l/PortableAreaDemo.rar?dl=0)